# Explanation needed for entry in gitlab.rb file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ruby, gitlab

in a project I´m working I got the task of being responsible for our gitlab server. In the gitlab.rb of this existing service I found the following line:

`nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /.well-known { root /var/www/letsencrypt; }"`

Can anyone explain me what´s happening there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's redirecting requests to gitlabserver.tld/.well-known to /var/www/letsencrypt. Let's Encrypt verifies you own a domain by placing the .well-known directory in the root of your webserver than attempting to read files from there.

So the config line is basically to allow letsencrypt verification for free SSL certificates.

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config']
```

allows you to specify custom configuration for nginx which is the web server gitlab uses. Info on nginx location can be found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Great so far! Could you explain the syntax for me?